# How to fix/troubleshoot AkamaiGHost TCP_Miss and 500 Errors

Tags: http, cdn, 500-error, 503-error

I have a java application running on a server in South America at the moment, and using Akamai's CDN.

When I check the errors, i sometimes get the error: "HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable" and "500 Internal Server Error", TCP_MISS from deploy.akamaitechnologies.com (AkamaiGHost/) (-).

What does this mean, and how can I fix this?

I am currently a student, and not so experienced, that is why I need help. All help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I take it you use somebody else's service over Akamai? Otherwise, talking to them would be the logical point to start? There's no way you can fix it from outside.